# Integrate $\frac{\sin^2(2t)}{4}$ from $0$ to $2\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration

Im trying to integrate $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{\sin^2(2t)}{4} dt$$  and I'm stuck..

Im at the end of multivariable calculus so no good solutions for these "simpler" problems are shown in the book at this point.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: Does the book not have single variable chapters too? Usually integrals like these are found in a section called "trigonometric integrals"

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\sin^2 x = \frac{1}{2}\Big(1 - \cos 2x \Big)$$

Take $x = 2t$.

Comment: (+1) this is the approach that first comes to mind. However, when the integral is over the proper interval, it's fun to use the fact that $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, you're right. (+1).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that by shifting by $\pi/4$ on the circle we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2(2t)}4\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^2(2t+\pi/2)}4\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^2(2t)}4\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}
$$
Now, consider the sum
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2(2t)}4\mathrm{d}t+\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^2(2t)}4\mathrm{d}t
$$

Answer (score 0):

Double angle formula: $cos(2A)=1-2{sin}^2(A)$

Rearrange to give an expression for ${sin}^2(A)$ in terms of $cos(2A)$

In your case $A=2t$

The result should be fairly easy to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{4}sin^2(2t)dt = \frac{2}{4}\int_{0}^{\pi}sin^2(2t) = \frac{t-\sin(t)\cos(t)}{4}|_{0}^{\pi} = \pi/4$$

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the fact that $$ \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2(2x) \, dx = \int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2 (2x)\, dx \text{ and } \int_0^{2\pi} (\sin^2(2x) + \cos^2(2x))\, dx = \int_0^{2\pi} 1 \, dx = 2\pi$$ to conclude $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2(2x)}{4} \, dx = \frac{\pi}4.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin^2(\alpha)=\frac12-\frac12\cos2\alpha$$ oscillates symmetrically around $\dfrac12$. Integrating over an integer number of periods, we have $\dfrac14\dfrac122\pi$.